# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when using EJB client jar

Tags: java, ejb, noclassdeffounderror

I have several projects that interact with a "core" project via EJBs.
Most of these projects use the same `core.ejb.client.jar`.
One project however uses its own `core.external.ejb.client.jar`, which is made via copying the files that are for the only EJB that this project requires.
I have an EJB/interface with one method: `public Application findApp()`

Within the method it creates an instance of Services and within Services it imports the class "Code".
`core.external.ejb.client.jar` contains the related EJB/interface files that weblogic creates and the Application class. The other `core.ejb.client.jar` contains many other classes including `Code.class`.

When my project calls `findApp()` I get the following error, however there is no reference in `myportal` to the Code class.

> ERROR org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.DefaultDispatcherErrorHandler - Exception occurred during processing request: Method "execute" failed for object myportal.web.actions.HomeAction@31c178d3
>       ognl.MethodFailedException: Method "execute" failed for object myportal.web.actions.HomeAction@31c178d3
>               at ognl.OgnlRuntime.callAppropriateMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1556) ~[ognl-3.1.15.jar:?]
>               at ognl.ObjectMethodAccessor.callMethod(ObjectMethodAccessor.java:68) ~[ognl-3.1.15.jar:?]
>               at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.accessor.XWorkMethodAccessor.callMethodWithDebugInfo(XWorkMethodAccessor.java:98) ~[struts2-core-2.5.17.jar:2.5.17]
>               at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.accessor.XWorkMethodAccessor.callMethod(XWorkMethodAccessor.java:90) ~[struts2-core-2.5.17.jar:2.5.17]
>               at ognl.OgnlRuntime.callMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1620) ~[ognl-3.1.15.jar:?]
>               at ognl.ASTMethod.getValueBody(ASTMethod.java:91) ~[ognl-3.1.15.jar:?]
>               at ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateGetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:212) ~[ognl-3.1.15.jar:?]
>               at ognl.SimpleNode.getValue(SimpleNode.java:258) ~[ognl-3.1.15.jar:?]
>               at ognl.Ognl.getValue(Ognl.java:470) ~[ognl-3.1.15.jar:?]
>               at ognl.Ognl.getValue(Ognl.java:434) ~[ognl-3.1.15.jar:?]
>               at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil$3.execute(OgnlUtil.java:401) ~[struts2-core-2.5.17.jar:2.5.17]
>       ...
>       Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: core/common/business/Code;
>               at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_152]
>               at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583) ~[?:1.8.0_152]
>               at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:2068) ~[?:1.8.0_152]
>               at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.getDeclaredSUID(ObjectStreamClass.java:1803) ~[?:1.8.0_152]
>               at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.access$700(ObjectStreamClass.java:79) ~[?:1.8.0_152]
>               at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$2.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:494) ~[?:1.8.0_152]
>               at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$2.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:482) ~[?:1.8.0_152]
>               at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_152]
>               at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.(ObjectStreamClass.java:482) ~[?:1.8.0_152]
>               at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookup(ObjectStreamClass.java:379) ~[?:1.8.0_152]
>               at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:669) ~[?:1.8.0_152]
>               at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1880) ~[?:1.8.0_152]
>               at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1746) ~[?:1.8.0_152]
>               at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2037) ~[?:1.8.0_152]
>               at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1568) ~[?:1.8.0_152]
>               at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:428) ~[?:1.8.0_152]
>               at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:797) ~[?:1.8.0_152]
>               at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
>               at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_152]
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_152]
>               at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1158) ~[?:1.8.0_152]
>               at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2173) ~[?:1.8.0_152]
>               at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2064) ~[?:1.8.0_152]
>               at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1568) ~[?:1.8.0_152]
>               at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:428) ~[?:1.8.0_152]
>               at weblogic.rmi.extensions.server.CBVInputStream.readObject(CBVInputStream.java:64) ~[com.bea.core.weblogic.rmi.client.jar:12.2.1.3]
>               at weblogic.rmi.internal.ServerRequest.unmarshalReturn(ServerRequest.java:127) ~[com.bea.core.weblogic.rmi.client.jar:12.2.1.3]
>               at weblogic.rmi.cluster.ClusterableRemoteRef.invoke(ClusterableRemoteRef.java:555) ~[com.bea.core.weblogic.rmi.client.jar:12.2.1.3]
>               at weblogic.rmi.cluster.ClusterableRemoteRef.invoke(ClusterableRemoteRef.java:313) ~[com.bea.core.weblogic.rmi.client.jar:12.2.1.3]
>               at core.common.ejb.external.core_ExternalPortalEJB_vl7zv5_ExternalPortalInterfaceImpl_12213_WLStub.getApplicationList(Unknown Source) ~[core.external.ejbclient.jar:?]
>               at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_152]
>               at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_152]
>               at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_152]
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_152]
>               at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.RemoteBusinessIntfProxy.invoke(RemoteBusinessIntfProxy.java:86) ~[com.oracle.weblogic.ejb.jar:12.2.1.3]
>               at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy752.getApplicationList(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
>               at myportal.web.actions.HomeAction.execute(HomeAction.java:58) ~[_wl_cls_gen.jar:?]
>               at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_152]
>               at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_152]
>               at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_152]
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_152]
>               at ognl.OgnlRuntime.invokeMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:899) ~[ognl-3.1.15.jar:?]
>               at ognl.OgnlRuntime.callAppropriateMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1544) ~[ognl-3.1.15.jar:?]

Answer (score 0):

Well I stupidly was searching only for an import statement of the Code class.  However the Application class and Code class are in the same folder and therefore didn't require an import statement.  The Application class refers to the code class and that is why I am getting the error.